# How to show list of Products coming from spring rest webservice on html page

Tags: java, web-services, spring-data, spring-rest

I have created a spring RESTFul web service using spring boot, spring-data.
This url(/api/products) returns a list of product object in json format.

This is my all spring data rest service code for repository and controller

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

And below is the json response

```
products: [ 

    {
    description: "some product 1",
    price: 100,
    imageUrl: "image url",
    _links: {
    self: {
    href: "http://localhost:8080/products/1"
    },
    product: {
    href: "http://localhost:8080/products/1"
    }
    }
    },
    {
    description: "some product 2",
    price: 200,
    imageUrl: "image url",
    _links: {
    self: {
    href: "http://localhost:8080/products/2"
    },
    product: {
    href: "http://localhost:8080/products/2"
    }
    }
    }
    ]
```

Q. How to consume this rest path on client side and display it on html page in tabular format ?

Comment: what is your front-end built in?

Comment: haven't build yet, i want to learn how to consume and show it on the html page.

Comment: kind of depends on what you use on your front-end. the chance for it to be html is quite small, since html isn't dynamic. most likely, you'll be using jsp, jsf, angular, ...

Comment: you can receive json as response via ajax and mapped it to html table via jquery. You can ask if you need code sample

Comment: yes code sample

Comment: have you checked any samples/tutorials online? what have you got so far?

Comment: https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/021-consume-get-request-spring-rest-webservice-jquery/

Comment: its not so helpful with @RespositoryRestResource or may be i am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using jquery ajax, datatables also give some nice look with bootstrap